# Как представить объект datetime с timezone строкой?

Tags: python, datetime, format

Например, мне нужно время формата `2022-11-14 18:01:01+04:00`;
я использую формат `'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%Z'`, который представляет `2022-11-14 18:01:01+04`. Как сделать, чтобы было `2022-11-14 18:01:01+04:00`?

Comment: Как вариант - просто добавьте к результирующей строке `:00`. Т.к. смещение всегда идет в целых часах, минуты всегда равны нулю.

Comment: @DmitryK не всегда https://www.timeanddate.com/time/time-zones-interesting.html

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, pytz вам поможет:

```
import datetime
import pytz
d = datetime.datetime.now()
print(pytz.timezone('Europe/Moscow').localize(d).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z'))
```

> 2022-11-14 13:56:55+0300

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вот так:

```
import datetime
def dt():
    dateTime = datetime.datetime.today()
    cstTimeDelta = datetime.timedelta(hours=+4)
    tzObject = datetime.timezone(cstTimeDelta, name="CST")
    cstTimeNow = dateTime.replace(tzinfo=tzObject)
    print(cstTimeNow.isoformat(" ", "seconds"))
```

итог будет вот такой:

```
2022-11-14 14:03:38+04:00
```